# selenium - send basic authentication while the password contains "@"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, basic-authentication, q

Our test environment is using a basic authentication and I'm trying to send the parameters in the URL header.
The only problem is, our password already contains "@", which means everything after it is considered as the website URL itself.
I've been trying to use "%40" which represents this character but it didn't work.
Here's the header assuming the username="username" and the password is "my@password":
driver.get("https://username:my%40password@test.website.com");

It used to work on my older computer, but something doesn't work on this one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check if your web-app supports API-Key. Use it instead of password

Comment: It's strange....without sending it trough Selenium does it works?

Answer (score 0):

> It used to work on my older computer

How long ago did it actually work? This old Chrome browser feature was removed from Chrome for years, but I learned from a bug report I filed that it's been brought back, although it only works in Selenium, not for a regular Chrome user in the address bar.

Perhaps Chrome's current "resurrected" name:password@ feature no longer supports the %40 trick you used to use?